# How can I match rows two by two in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a very simple dataframe:

```
+--+------+
|Id|Amount|
+--+------+
|0 |3.47  |
|1 |-3.47 |
|2 |3.47  |
|3 |3.47  |
|4 |2.01  |
|5 |-2.01 |
|6 |-2.01 |
|7 |7.65  |
|8 |7.65  |
+--+------+
```

I'd like to match line 0 and 1, 4 and 5, and return line 2 and 3. There are several solutions to this, returning lines 0 and 2 is also fine.

The general idea is that they should be matched 2 by 2 and the leftovers returned. It should return nothing if every line has a match and should return all lines that couldn't be paired that way.

Any idea how to do that?

Expected result:

```
+--+------+
|Id|Amount|
+--+------+
|0 |3.47  |
|2 |3.47  |
|6 |-2.01 |
|7 |7.65  |
|8 |7.65  |
+--+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

result = df.withColumn(
    'cnt', 
    F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('Amount'))
).withColumn(
    'min_cnt',
    F.min('cnt').over(Window.partitionBy(F.abs('Amount')))
).withColumn(
    'max_cnt',
    F.max('cnt').over(Window.partitionBy(F.abs('Amount')))
).withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('Amount').orderBy('Id'))
).filter(
    'rn > min_cnt or max_cnt = min_cnt'
).select('Id', 'Amount')

result.show()
+---+------+
| Id|Amount|
+---+------+
|  6| -2.01|
|  7|  7.65|
|  8|  7.65|
|  2|  3.47|
|  3|  3.47|
+---+------+
```

Comment: Does it still work with the line I added? I'm not very familiar with `groupBy(greatest)`

Comment: I realised the previous code won't give correct results when there are rows like (1,-1,1,-1). Edited to use another way which should hopefully give correct results.

Comment: Great. I'll check that out. I'll upvote and accept the solution on Monday if it works.

Comment: Ok I missed to mention the case of a dangling value that doesn't match anything. I can start with your query and try to add this case.

Comment: Yes, and I think you wrote it in between my edits. Because in the meantime I though about the last corner case where there are multiple non-matching values. This is definitely close though!

Comment: But I think I just need to swap max_cnt = 1 with min_cnt = max_cnt. Took the liberty to edit it in myself. Please edit it again if you think this is incorrect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually I think I'm back to square 1. I must implement a threshold in the comparison, which makes partitionBy Amount not usable :(
I think I must make another SO question for that...

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat that would be tricky... yes, having another question would be good

Comment: The new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221901/how-can-i-match-double-rows-with-a-threshold-in-spark

Comment: I wonder if you can round each row to the nearest 0.5 (or whatever threshold you're using)? Then the answer might still work.

Comment: 12.8 should be able to match with values ranging from -12.3 and -13.3. But 13.8 should also be able to match with -13.3 and -14.3. 12.8 should not match -14.3, so I don't think rouding would work since 12.8 and 13.8 will have to be in the same group but not matching the same rows. Maybe I need to split with two roundings: upper and lower?

Comment: Legacy code is doing everything in RDDs and builds a list with all values and then removing values that match 2 by 2. At this point I'm wondering if a UDF doing roughly the same thing is not the way to go...

Comment: ya, it may be good to write a udf for this. It's really hard to write a reliable function in pure spark. Also I think some clustering algorithms might be helpful to do a grouping before applying the function in my answer.