# How can I match double rows with a threshold in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very simple dataframe:

```
+--+------+
|Id|Amount|
+--+------+
|0 |3.47  |
|1 |-3.47 |
|2 |3.47  |
|3 |3.47  |
|4 |2.02  |
|5 |-2.01 |
|6 |-2.01 |
|7 |7.65  |
|8 |7.65  |
+--+------+
```

I'd like to match lines that cancel each other given a threshold value (let's say 0.5).
So in this case, match line 0 and 1, 4 and 5, and return line 2 and 3. There are several solutions to this, returning lines 0 and 2 is also fine.

The general idea is that they should be matched 2 by 2 and the leftovers returned. It should return nothing if every line has a match and should return all lines that couldn't be paired that way.

Any idea how to do that?

Expected result:

```
+--+------+
|Id|Amount|
+--+------+
|0 |3.47  |
|2 |3.47  |
|6 |-2.01 |
|7 |7.65  |
|8 |7.65  |
+--+------+
```

I've been thinking about using an `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`, but I'm not sure whether or not it's enough. Especially because I think it can only return one value per group of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with an UDF. Writing UDFs in Java is seriously overcomplicated...

**If anybody can see a way to simplify that mess, please post or comment.**

```java
private UDF1<WrappedArray<Row>, Row[]> matchData() {
    return (data) -> {
        List<Data> dataList = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(data).stream().map(Data::fromRow).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Set<Data> matched = new HashSet<>();

        for (Data element : dataList) {
            if (matched.contains(element)) continue;

            dataList.stream().filter(e -> !matched.contains(e) && e != element)
                    .filter(e -> Math.abs(e.getAmount() + element.getAmount()) < THRESHOLD
                            && Math.signum(e.getAmount()) != Math.signum(element.getAmount()))
                    .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> Math.abs(e.getAmount() + element.getAmount())))
                    .ifPresent(e -> {
                        matched.add(e);
                        matched.add(element);
                    });
        }


        if (matched.size() != dataList.size()) {
            return dataList.stream().map(Data::toRow).toArray(Row[]::new);
        } else {
            return new Row[0];
        }
    };
}
```

With the Data class (using Lombok):

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
public final class Data {
    private String name;
    private Double amount;

    public static Data fromRow(Row r) {
        return new Data(
                r.getString(r.fieldIndex("name")),
                r.getDouble(r.fieldIndex("amount")));
    }

    public Row toRow() {
        return RowFactory.create(name, amount);
    }
}
```

I'm returning the whole set in case it didn't work, this is actually what I need in my case.

Comment: And I'm not even posting schema definition and the Dataset call chain part of it.